# How to use timeoutException method of FluentWait?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

While trying to use timeoutException method of fluentWait class,

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver);
wait.timeoutException("test timeoutException",new MyException("hello"));
```

Getting warning that

```
The method timeoutException(String, Throwable) from the type FluentWait<WebDriver> is not visible
```

Why So? How to use this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By overriding timeoutException method, we can trigger a different exception when wait timeout.
Consider following code in which timeoutException Method is overwritten.

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> wait=new  FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver){
    @Override
    protected RuntimeException timeoutException(String Message,Throwable lastException)    
    {
        throw new MyException("A New Exception instead of TimeOutException");
    }
};   
wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
    .withTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
  public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
  }
});
```

So when timeout occurs , instead of TimeoutException, a Custom Exception will be thrown

```
com.example.tests.MyException: A New Exception instead of TimeOutException
at com.example.tests.sampleTest$1.timeoutException(sampleTest.java:40)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:228)
at com.example.tests.sampleTest.test(sampleTest.java:45)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look into `FluentWait`, you will notice that `timeoutExcpetion` has protected access, hence you cannot use it like this.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you generally use it like:

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver);
wait.withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
        .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .withMessage("Trololo")
        .until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id")));
```

Comment: Thanks, Erki, But this is not what i was looking for, i am studying selenium and understood how to use different methods of FluentWait except timeoutException. though by paying attention to your hint of protected method, I was able to find out its usage and updating it as answer.